# Get ContentId (or any FileAttachment properties) without ContentBytes with Outlook REST API

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

In my application that uses the Outlook REST API, in order to support inlined images in html emails, I need to retrieve the `ContentId` of the [File Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#FileAttachmentResource) of a given email.

**Note:** in an html email inlined images are html tags of the form `<input scr="cid:mycontentid">`

I manage to get this information at url `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments`

The problem is the returned json also contains the `ContentBytes` which can be arbitrary big for large attachments.

I tried several syntaxes to retrieve only the fields that I need such as:

`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments?$select=Id,ContentId` or `'$select=Id&$expand=ContentId'`

none of them worked, resulting in a bad request

```
{"error":{"code":"RequestBroker-ParseUri","message":"Could not find a property named 'ContentId' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Attachment'."}}
```

The expected types at url `'/attachments'` are `Microsoft.OutlookServices.Attachment` which is a base type for [File Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#FileAttachmentResource) and Item Attachment.

I would like to retrieve the specific member for File Attachments (`ContentId`) or to discard the heavy `ContentBytes` contained in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint of `me/messages/{message_id}/attachments` return the collection of attachment.

The **ContentId** is the property of **FileAttachment**. You can use the code below to get the **contentId** of fileAttachment:

```
GET: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{messageId}/attachments?$select=Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment/ContentId
```

**EDIT:**
*Remark*: if you want to retrieve other field, say `Name` note that `$select=Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment/ContentId,Name` will work while that `$select=Name,Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment/ContentId` will throw the error mentioned in the original question

Comment: Thank you! It works, Actually I tried such request before but with other fields in the $select and I got an error. The ContentId must be retrieved first, I have edited your answer because it seemed important to me.